# Что такое бзда?

Tags: словоприменение

Интересуюсь, что такое бзда. Помогите

UPDATE:

That's ridiculous. What is your problem people? I don't understand downvotes. There is such word, all I am asking is for some help explaining it

- [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3)
- [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

So what is wrong with it?

Comment: нет такого слова

Comment: Есть:https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: большинство - опечатки

Comment: Spell it right then

Comment: @1453 Is it ѣзда you're looking for? If so, it's the "old orthography" for modern _езда_. Note the first letter is not _Б_, it's a vowel that got replaced with _Е_.

Comment: Google ngrams has a lot misspelled words in old books, and even some books that have wrong years (1875 instead of 1975), so it is alway better to open book search to see the detailed results.

Answer (score 5):

Во всех примерах на Google Books — неправильно считанные слова с буквой ять: ѣзда (езда, ride), звѣзда (звезда, star), уѣзда (genitive of уезд, county)

В ссылках на форумы — иногда просторечное существительное от [«бздеть»](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C), или эвфемизм в значении [«пизда»](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0). Как правило, никакой смысловой нагрузки не несет.